# what does this dictionary iteration mean in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, iteration

A dictionary and an iteration operation in swfit

```
let namesAndScores = ["Anna": 2, "Brian": 2, "Craig": 8, "Donna"; 6]
for key in namesAndScores.keys {
    print("\(key), ", terminator: "")
}
print("")
```

the result is Brian, Anna, Craig, Donna,

what is this operation doing? and why does "terminator: " not appear in the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > ### Q: what is this operation doing?

The following line is a dictionary of type `[String : Int]`

```
let namesAndScores = ["Anna": 2, "Brian": 2, "Craig": 8, "Donna": 6]
```

Next, take note of the following line in your loop:

```
namesAndScores.keys
```

This `.keys` property gives us a *new **array*** composed of *just* the keys from your dictionary. For example:

```
let keys = ["Anna", "Brian", "Craig", "Donna"]
```

Next, you're simply looping through the array I depicted above:

```
for key in namesAndScores.keys {
    print("\(key), ", terminator: "")
}
```

> > ### Q: and why does "terminator: " not appear in the result?

Terminator is just a parameter that lets you set the print line terminator. In other words, it lets you chose what gets printed after each line. By default its `"\n"` which gives us a new line.

In your example you have: `print("\(key), ", terminator: "")`. With your print statement's **terminator** set to `""`. You're simply telling your `print()` function to print *without* a trailing newline. Which prints your values like this:

> Brian, Anna, Craig, Donna,

However, you could pass any string into your terminator parameter for example:

```
print("\(key), ", terminator: " -hi- ")
```

Which would give you this:

> Brian,  -hi- Anna,  -hi- Craig,  -hi- Donna,  -hi-

So, when you just use the common `print("\(key), ")` without setting the terminator, your **terminator** parameter gets a *default* value which is equivalent to:

```
print("\(key), ", terminator: "\n")
```

This prints each item on a *new line*, like so:

> Brian,
>   Anna,
>   Craig,
>   Donna,

update based on comment:

> > ### Q: Why is Brian before Anna in the result while Brian is after
> >
> > ### Anna in the Dictionary?

Dictionaries are unsorted. So, the resulting array from `.keys` will be in an unpredictable order. Fortunately, you are able to sort the resulting array in place by simply adding `.sort(<)` in your for-loop.

```
for key in namesAndScores.keys.sort(<) {
    print("\(key), ", terminator: "")
}
```

prints:

> Anna, Brian, Craig, Donna,

Comment: great!!! and one more question, why is Brian before Anna in the result while Brian is after Anna in the Dictionary?

Comment: i sure selected your answer. and thanks for your help.